# AngularJS : Showing content on the next page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have following structure in my html page:

```
<ul data-ng-controller="ListCtrl">
   <li data-ng-repeat="record in records">
      <div>.............</div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I have total 15 records which are displaying on the same page.

I need to divide these pages like 1-5, 6-10, 11-15, so if i added limitTo: 5 then it showing only first 5 records. I need to see the rest of records also like 6-10 & 11-15 on the next page.

Is there any kind of filter in angularJS or any other way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom "from" filter:

```
app.filter('from', function() {
    return function(data, from) {
        return data.slice(parseInt(from));
    }
});
```

es: data-ng-repeat="record in records | from: 5 | limitTo: 5"

Comment: Thanks..!but the problem is in this case i am able to see the last page only means 11-15. why so..?

Comment: yes when i applied form :3 | limitTo : 3 it will display only the last page 13-15.please help.?

Comment: that's fine but at a time is it able to see the content of page one, page two and three as like pagination..?

Comment: I want that when i click on the page -1 it will display 1-5 when on two it will be 6-10 & on wards. see the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jvaibhav/QcdmS/1/ . Is there any other way to do this other then pagination ..?

Answer (score 1):

Try angularjs ui directives based on bootstrap

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: thanks for reply. you mean pagination..? Is there any shortcut other then pagination ?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I don't think this answer is particularly useful, as you're just posting a link without any guidance.

Comment: @Alan: yes, I already knew about that link but do you know any other method other then pagination..?